# How to change "On the app store" verbiage

Tags: ios

So a rather minor point, but something I'd like to fix if I can. When I search for my app on Google, I get my app name + "On the App Store". But as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

But looking at other apps, `BuzzFeed` for example yields this:

[image]

and NYTimes

[image]

I did read up on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsMetadata.html) documentation that says something about meta data, but it's unclear **which** meta data property they're referring to.

If I wanted to change the `On the App Store` verbiage, which meta data property do I need to set? Since it's not instant results, no way for me to know for sure.

Comment: The documentation you linked is about in-app purchases. The search result just takes your app's name.

Comment: I got "BuzzFeed – Tasty, News, Quizzes, and beyond on the App Store", on my side. My guess, is that on yours, it's just ellipsed: "on the... - iTunes - Apple", instead of "on the App Store - iTunes - Apple", in other words: long name (which I personally dislike) is the trick.

Comment: Eh.. maybe not. Updated question with a new screenshot. NYTimes seems to not have the 'on the App Store' at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change the app name from `Newser On the AppStore` to `Newser - On the AppStore`

Comment: After searching for the other two example apps this is actually correct. The titles are just too long to fully show it but they simple have a longer title with "on the App Store" appended to the end.

Comment: Wait so if it's too long it won't show `on the App Store` but if it isn't too long it does? Can you show me documentation for that?

Comment: While the real answer is, just make app name long enough, this answer is good enough.